# Toggle checkbox before send a form

Tags: jquery

I want to send the form after clicking on the label next to checkbox. So I have created simple function below. Html code:

```
 <input class="myinput" type="checkbox" name="photo"id="photo" value="1" />
 <label class="autosend" for="photo">Photos</label>
 <input class="myinput" type="checkbox" name="text"id="photo" value="1" />
 <label class="autosend" for="text">Text</label>
```

Jquery code:

```
 $('.autosend').click(function() {
 $('form#search').submit();
 });
```

The main problem is - after clicking on the label form is being sent, but without checked checkbox. Why is that? I see in my webbrowser that checkbox is checking just for a few seconds before send. Is there any way to use this jquery code above with possibility to check or uncheck checkbox which belongs to a specific label?

I know I can add additional line before send a form:

```
 $(this).prev(".myinput").attr('checked','checked');
```

But that is not solution, because I need to check if previous input is checked and just toggle (between state checked and not checked).

Comment: So you want to have photo unchecked when text is checked? if so, wouldn't a radio be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
 $('form#search').submit();
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple. Works prefect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can send the form on the change event of checkbox:

```
$('input[name=text]').on('change', function(){
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: That is fine solution, but I have more inputs than one named "text".

Comment: It's not just on the text input, but on both checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `for` attribute of the `label` element should be set to the `id` of the related input.

```
<input class="myinput" type="checkbox" name="photo" id="photo" value="1" />
<label class="autosend" for="photo">Photos</label>

<input class="myinput" type="checkbox" name="text" id="text" value="1" />
<label class="autosend" for="text">Text</label>
```

Secondly you should use the `change` event to cover users selecting the box via keyboard input, and you should also check to make sure that the box is being checked, not unchecked

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('form#search').submit();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dK4Wa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `for` attribute of the `<label>` element corresponds to the **ID** not the name of the element that you want it to refer to. Your label and your checkbox aren't connected, so clicking the label won't toggle the checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I have it, I forgot to put it into code in here. But I already found solution metioned below by someone else. Thanks for answer.